# How to change active page id in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I can get a current page id from  `$.mobile.activePage.attr('id');`

How can I replace this id without changing the whole page. Just replace page ID.

Suppose current page id is **page_channel**. I want to make this id **page_channel_1** and all element inside in it will remain same.

Comment: `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id', 'new id')`, jQM 1.4.